# How to push data from a website to another website

Tags: python, django, angular

In my Django + Angular web app, I create a job description using a form. Afterward, I need to push the same job description to an external career website of a company. How can I achieve this?

Comment: By calling an API from the external website. If they don't have an API and you don't own the site, you can't. You can't just go around updating other people's sites unless they provide a method for you to do so :D

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can automate the process of registering a user and posting a job on a target website (using Selenium and Python). The process is straightforward. Here's a basic example to illustrate the steps:

```
# fill out the form
login_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name=login]')
login_input.send_keys('Test login')

password_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name=pass]')
password_input.send_keys('Test password')

# submit the form
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button').click()
```

To assist you further, here are some useful resources:

1. [Using Selenium with Python for Automated Testing](https://saucelabs.com/resources/blog/selenium-with-python-for-automated-testing)
2. [Solve reCAPTCHA 2 in Selenium (Using Python)](https://antcpt.com/eng/information/recaptcha-2-selenium.html)